# Polling objects for data in Java

Tags: java, select

I have many `PacketConnection` objects connected to remote computers.  Each `PacketConnection` has thread-safe (`synchronized`) read and write methods that accept `Packets`.  Other classes should not have access to the enclosed streams.

I would like the connections' owner to be notified when a `PacketConnection` has data to read (it can block until an event; spinning the CPU in a while-loop is obviously unwanted).  The owner would then ask the appropriate object to read and return a `Packet`.

What is the most idomatic way to accomplish this?

Comment: But then how do I fire events?  Each `PacketConnection` should not have its own thread.

Comment: Eh, how does it know when there is data to read then? Something is not adding up here.

Comment: In C, I can have several sockets and call `select` on all of them.  `select` will return when one or more has data.  How can I accomplish the same idea in Java, but with arbitrary objects?

Comment: Maybe something like a [Future](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/AsynchronousSocketChannel.html#read(java.nio.ByteBuffer))?

Comment: Isn't a Future for waiting for computation to complete?

Comment: Yes, something to complete, like receiving a packet. But I guess you rather want to go down to the bits and bytes, in that case the answer of cpurdy will suit you.

Comment: How is receiving a packet (and thus filling a Future) possible without having a thread for each object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Java NIO to access the "selector" functionality to tell you which sockets have data that you can read. [`SocketChannel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/SocketChannel.html) represents a selectable Socket. You then call `select()` on the [`Selector`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/Selector.html) to determine if any of the sockets are readable; you can provide a selection time-out if necessary.

Comment: Please show some code, and/or link to the classes you want to point to. This is not a full answer as it is.

Comment: +1 very good answer, no spoonfeeding necessary. It's not really a full *question* as it is IMHO.

Comment: A followup:  `SocketChannel` will indeed work quite well for what I described.  You can even get a traditional stream from it with a function call.  I didn't mention, however, that I need an SSL-enabled socket (I figured that would be a trivial change).  It is *not* trivial; you must manually manage the SSL state machine with an `SSLEngine`.  For the scale of my app, which is a few dozen connections at most, it is much less trouble (and little overhead) to just use a blocking thread for each connection.

Comment: Yes, you're right. And SSLEngine is tricky to get right. (We've done it, but it was a lot more work than it first looked like!)